# Facebook Session incorrectly reports that it is not open

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have an application that requires Facebook login, which I implemented according to the demo example (not using `UiLifecycleHelper`, though I have tried adding it and it seems to make no difference).  Basically when I hit the login button, dismiss the Facebook login web dialog, then hit the button again, I get this exception:

```
06-10 11:48:48.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6482): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
06-10 11:48:48.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6482):     at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:947)
06-10 11:48:48.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6482):     at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Session.java:385)
06-10 11:48:48.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6482):     at com.[my package].SocialAbstractActivity$FacebookClickListener.onClick(SocialAbstractActivity.java:140)
```

This is caused by this code:

```
if(!activeSession.isOpened()) {
    activeSession.openForRead(getReadOpenRequest());
    showProgressDialog(R.string.dialog_logging_title, R.string.dialog_logging_message);
}
```

Why is `activeSession` reporting that it's not opened, but then throwing this exception?

Moreover, why do I still get this bug *even after* calling `activeSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();`?